# bootstrap-timepicker not working

Tags: javascript, html, timepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to get timepicker to work similarly to datepicker:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date *" id="caldate" required data-validation-required-message="Please choose date.">

            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
            </span>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
        $('div.input-group.date').datepicker({
            startDate: date
        });
    </script>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
            <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="form-control input-small">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
            </span>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
    </script>
```

Datepicker works, but Timepicker dos not show up when clicked. Did I do something wrong in the javascript part?

Comment: Is JQuery loaded before these scripts?

Comment: yes, and it is working for datepicker

Comment: I have the feeling that #timepicker1 should be replaced with something else, similarly to the datepicker div.input-group.date

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes:TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
 
$('#timepicker1').timepicker();

Comment: Then you probably don't have the timepicker js file loaded correctly.

Comment: Yes i was calling the wrong name (min version). Now error is not appearing anymore, and a default 1:30 PM shows up, but still not able to see anything when clicking on time button

Comment: nevermind. It got fixed when i changed     <link href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css"  rel="stylesheet"> to     <link href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In head

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

In body

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date *" id="caldate" required data-validation-required-message="Please choose date.">

            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
            </span>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
        //    $('div.input-group.date').datepicker({
        $('#caldate').datepicker({
            startDate: date
        });
    </script>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
            <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="form-control input-small">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
            </span>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#timepicker1').timepicker({
            defaultTime: 'current',
            minuteStep: 1
        });
    </script>
```